# How to get around "missing 1 required positional argument" error when doing an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I get a `TypeError: options() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'` on the following code:

```
def post_ad(request):
    filename = request.POST.get('temp_s3_url')
    boost_form = AdvertisePostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if boost_form.is_valid():
        instance = boost_form.save(commit=False)
        if Post.objects.filter(hash=instance.hash).exists():
            instance.hash = random_string()

        instance.ad = True
        instance.save()
        context = {
            'hash': instance.hash,
        }
        return options(request, context)

    context = {
        'boost_form': boost_form
    }
    return render(request, 'advertising/post_ad.html', context)

def options(request, context):
    ad = get_object_or_404(AdvertisePost, hash=context['hash'])

    if request.is_ajax():
        total_price = request.POST.get('total_price')
        print('Total price:', total_price)

    context = {
        'ad': ad
    }

    return render(request, 'advertising/options.html', context)
```

**js**

```
    ...
    var total_price = Math.round(amount);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/advertise/options/",
        data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val(),
            total_price: total_price,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('Success!');
            console.log(amount);
        }

    });

}
```

when I remove `context` as a positional argument, or change `def options(request, context):` to `def options(request, context="something"):`  - it works (there's no error and the ajax call successfully prints in my view. However I have to keep the `context` as it has important data. How can I get around this problem?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Where would the context dict come from when you call this view directly from the URL?

Comment: That's the problem, I can't pass the `context` parameter when the call the `options()` URL through AJAX.

Comment: I suggest you make another function for the ajax view and call `options` from it.

Comment: @Zorgan but your requirement doesn't seem to make sense. If you can't pass it, how can your view depend on it? It needs to come from somewhere.

Comment: What is supposed to be in the `context`? If it is something you have to pass through, you can just as well put it in your `POST` data.

Comment: @xpy it's just a string but how do I get that string from `post_ad()` to `options.html`?

Comment: Can I create a default for `context`?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get around it by removing the `context` positional argument and simply getting the latest model created by adding `ad = AdvertisePost.objects.order_by('-id')[0]` to my `options()` view - as that was what I was passing through in my initial context.